# Передача Date и АrrayList<String> Parcel

Tags: android, дата, arraylist, android-parcelable

Есть класс `Note`

```
public class Note implements Parcelable {
private String author, title;
private Date dateCreate, dateEdit;
private ArrayList<String> bodyNote;

public Note() {
}

public Note(String author, String title, Date dateCreate, Date dateEdit,
            ArrayList<String> bodyNote) {
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.dateCreate = dateCreate;
    this.dateEdit = dateEdit;
    this.bodyNote = bodyNote;
}

public Note(Parcel parcel){
    String[] data = new String[2];
    parcel.readStringArray(data);
    author = data[0];
    title = data[1];

}
```

Примитивные данные для конструктора `Parcel` я создал, проблема с данными типа `Date` и `ArrayList<String>`.
Подскажите как их правильно создать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Должно работать

```
public class Note implements Parcelable {
    private String author, title;
    private Date dateCreate, dateEdit;
    private ArrayList<String> bodyNote;

    public Note() {
    }

    protected Note(Parcel in) {
        author = in.readString();
        title = in.readString();
        dateCreate = new Date(in.readLong());
        dateEdit = new Date(in.readLong());
        bodyNote = in.createStringArrayList();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(author);
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeLong(dateCreate.getTime());
        dest.writeLong(dateEdit.getTime());
        dest.writeStringList(bodyNote);
    }

    public static final Creator<Note> CREATOR = new Creator<Note>() {
        @Override
        public Note createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Note(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Note[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Note[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Жаль, что сам не додумался Date перевести в long.